# How to block Googlebot from accessing one specific page

Tags: htaccess, googlebot, spam

I am getting spammed by this IP: `66.249.79.70`, and this website is telling  me that it is from Google: `https://ipinfo.io/66.249.79.70`

It is filling one of my input boxes and keeps posting. I want to block this bot (with IP address: `66.249.79.xxx`) from accessing one specific page (e.g., `www.example.com/blocked.php`) using an *.htaccess* file, how can I do that? I don't want to block the IP address completely though because I don't doubt it's from Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this does appear to be the real Googlebot, the recommended way to block access/crawling is to use `/robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /blocked.php
```

However, if you still want to block this IP using `.htaccess` then you can do something like the following, near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =66.249.79.70
RewriteRule ^blocked\.php - [F]
```

This will return a "403 Forbidden" when a user with the above IP address attempts to access `/blocked.php`. Note that the "user/bot" still *tries* to access the URL by making a request, whereas with `robots.txt` they shouldn't even make the request (assuming they obey the robots.txt "standard"; which Googlebot does).

However, bear in mind that Googlebot can crawl from different IP addresses, so this may need to be updated in the future.

---

If you did want to block the *range* of IP addresses denoted by `66.249.79.xxx`, then you could change the above *condition* to:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^66\.249\.79\.
```

However, that could block more than just Googlebot and may not be any more successful at blocking Googlebot than checking the specific IP address above (Googlebot does not necessarily crawl on a continuous IP block).

Comment: The simple and efficient method is block it via robots.txt. `.htaccess` cause many problem as you said, and X robots header tag(like nofollow and noindex) does not stop Googlebot completely to crawl. Might setting up [crawl rate in search console helps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en) a little bit. Another thing is that OP should use some kind of capcha code to avoid auto fill up by Googlebot.

Comment: "User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /blocked.php " If i use this then google bot will not stop to crawl entire website right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Bots will crawl everything by default, you only need to include the URLs you want to block.

Comment: If i use this "User-agent: googlebot Disallow: /blocked.php " when google bot visits blocked.php what it will see?

Comment: Google will read and process your `/robots.txt` file (this can take a day or so - check in Google Search Console on the status). Once Google has processed your `/robots.txt` file then Googlebot simply won't visit `/blocked.php` at all. `robots.txt` blocks _crawling_.

Comment: @w3dk also oi can specify multiple pages right? In at this way  "User-agent: googlebot Disallow: /blocked.php Disallow: /blockedx.php Disallow: /blockedy.php"

Comment: How to use this rule for dynamic url as well? for example blocked.php?id=12

Comment: Yes. Note that robots.txt is _prefix matching_. So a directive like `Disallow: /blocked` will block all 3 URLs you just mentioned.